# How to determine if my mobile web app is running in Gmail's integrated browser?

Tags: android, mobile, gmail, chrome-custom-tabs

My mobile web app does not perform as well in Gmail's integrated browser when launched from a link in a user's Gmail message.

How can I determine that my app is running in GMail's integrated browser, or in Chrome Custom Tabs, or in GMail?  In this case I want to display a message to encourage the user to tap the vertical ellipse in the red banner and then to Open in Chrome.